# How to dynamically create input range element (and its event handler) inside ajaxStop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, leaflet, geojson

I am new to js development and ajax. I'm trying to writing a webpage that requests data from a server using ajax and uses the data to draw sets of geoJSON features on a map with leaflet (these feature sets must be toggleable to draw/undraw so I'm using leaflet's built-in functionality for this). Because I don't want to run into problems with loading, I have had to put all of my dynamic creation code in an 'ajaxStop' callback (ie the code will run after all ajax calls have finished).

Part of what I need to do is add a variable number of slider bars (this depends on whether or not a particular feature set has a time component). I have naively put this code and the code to attach an onchange event handler in the ajaxStop callback. The slider bar is created, but the event listener does not exist (nothing happens when I move the slider bar around when I added debug statements to the event handler).

**How it should work:**
The slider goes from one time period to another (corresponding to the minimum and maximum time in a time based feature set). When the slider bar is moved, then the feature set should change so that only the ones whose times are less than the slider bar value are in the array of iLayers for this feature set (basically a container for a set of features that allows feature sets to be toggleable on the leaflet map). The old global variable for all the arrays of iLayers are removed at the start of the event handler, updated, then re-added to the map. Currently everything except this time slider thing works.

Is this the right way to add a slider bar and its event handler in js? I haven't actually isolated the issue for sure, but considering that I have created dom elements and event handlers dynamically in the past with no trouble, I have a feeling this issue came up because this code is in ajaxStop.

I would really appreciate some advice if someone else dealt with this before. Also I realize that my code looks horrible right now, but I need to get this working in some capacity before I can clean things up. I didn't include global variable declarations and the rest of the code for conciseness (the post is massive enough as it is).

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
   var feat_num = 0;

   for (var gView = 0; gView < geoViews.length; ++gView) {
      var layers = geoViews[gView].layers;
      println("GeoView " +gView +": " +geoViews[gView].descriptor);

      for (var lay = 0; lay < layers.length; ++lay) {
         var features = geoViews[gView].layers[lay].features;
         var iLayers = new Array(features.length);
         var layer_min = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
         var layer_max = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
         var times = [];

         for (var feat = 0; feat < features.length; ++feat, ++feat_num) {
            geoViews[gView].layers[lay].features[feat] = feats[feat_num];

            var propsString = feats[feat_num].properties;
            var props = JSON.parse(propsString.replaceAll("'", '"'));

            if (props.hasOwnProperty("time")) {
               if (props.time < layer_min) layer_min = props.time;
               if (props.time > layer_max) layer_max = props.time;
               times.push(props.time);
            }
            iLayers[feat] = L.GeoJSON.geometryToLayer(feats[feat_num], null);
         }

         println("\u00A0" +"Layer " +lay +": " +layers[lay].uid);

         //Adds all features to overlay array on start
         var layer = geoViews[gView].layers[lay];
         layer.layerGroup = L.layerGroup(iLayers);
         L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: mapID, attribution: mbAttr});
         overlays[layer.uid] = layer.layerGroup;

         if (layer_max > Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) {
            print("\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0");
            print(new Date(layer_min));
            var s = addSlider(log, layer.uid, layer.features, layer_min, layer_max);
            sliders.push(s);

            //****This is not working (start)****
            s.addEventListener("onchange", function() {  //not working
               var iLayers;
               var time = slider.value;
               map.removeControl(overlays);
               for (var i; i < slider.possible.length; ++i) {
                  var props = JSON.parse(slider.possible[i].properties.replaceAll("'", '"'));
                  if (props.time <= time) {
                     iLayers[i] = L.GeoJSON.geometryToLayer(slider.possible[i], null); 
                  }
               }
               overlays[slider.uid] = iLayers;
               alert("trigger");
               L.control.layers(null, overlays).addTo(map);
            });
            //****This is not working (end)****

            log.appendChild(s);
            print(new Date(layer_max));
         }
      }
      L.control.layers(null, overlays).addTo(map);
      println(" ");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by sticking to my original idea and simply using this [leaflet slider bar plug-in](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider). Adding an event handler is then unnecessary because the plug-in deals with adding/removing features based on a provided property ('time' by default) based on the slider bar.